# Simple login page - form method post doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Hello I have simple login page which works fine when I am using bootstrap but I want to use angular material design.

I am looking for problem from 3-4 hrs and nothing. I think that form doesn't send any data like username, password and submit

There is full code of login

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="img/png" href="img/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <script src="../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.css" />
</head>

<body layout="row">
    <div layout="column" flex id="content" role="main" ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-app="MyApp">
        <md-content layout="vertical" flex id="content" layout-align="center center">
            <?php include "connect.php"; if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){ $username=$ _POST['username']; $password=md5($_POST[ 'password']); $stmt=$ db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=? AND password=? "); $stmt->bindParam(1, $username); $stmt->bindParam(2, $password); $stmt->execute(); $row = $stmt->fetch(); $user = $row['username']; $pass = $row['password']; $id = $row['id']; $type = $row['type']; if($user==$username && $pass==$password){ session_start(); $_SESSION['username'] = $user; $_SESSION['password'] = $pass; $_SESSION['id'] = $id; $_SESSION['type'] = $type; ?>
            <script>
                window.location.href = 'index.php'
            </script>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <div>
                <strong>Warning!</strong> Password or username are wrong!
            </div>
            <?php } } ?>
            <form method="post" name="loginForm" style="width:50vh">
                <br />
                <br />

                <md-toolbar>
                    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                        <h2>Login</h2>
                    </div>
                </md-toolbar>

                <md-dialog-content>
                    <div>
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label>Username:</label>
                            <input name="username" required>
                        </md-input-container>
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label>Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" required>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                </md-dialog-content>

                <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
                    <span flex></span>
                    <md-button type="submit" value="Login" class="md-primary">OK</md-button>
                    <md-button type="button" aria-label="Cancel">Cancel</md-button>
                </md-dialog-actions>
            </form>
        </md-content>

    </div>

    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="js/app.js"></script> -->
    <script>
        angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])

        .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

            $scope.radek = "Radek";
            console.log($scope.radek);

        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any error logs from the browser console?

Comment: no nothing even I click button or put wrong date

Comment: @Ixe There is log from server
 mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '_POST' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in /var/www/clients/client1/web14/web/login/login.php on line 21

Line 21 = <?php

Comment: Where is the [ng-submit directive?](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit). It would be a good idea to review: [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: Yes but when I do something like <form method="post" ng-submit="submit()">

I must write function with what?

Comment: Use the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to POST the request.

Comment: I do something wrong

Here is code of $http post. Can you look?
http://pastebin.com/bQLjBFXJ

login.php is my file of full code which I added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AngularJS, forms need an `ng-submit` directive.

```
<form method="post" name="loginForm" ng-submit="submit()">
```

Since the role of forms in client-side AngularJS applications is different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload that sends the data to the server. Instead some javascript logic should be triggered to handle the form submission in an application-specific way.

For this reason, **AngularJS prevents the default action** (form submission to the server) unless the  element has an action attribute specified.

You can use one of the following two ways to specify what javascript method should be called when a form is submitted:

- [ngSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) directive on the form element
- [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive on the first button or input field of type submit (input[type=submit])

For more information, see:

- [AngularJS form Directive API Reference - Submitting a Form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

---

> I do something wrong Here is code of $http post. Can you look?

With the AngularJS $http service, the default content type is `application/json` and data objects are automatically encoded into JSON strings.

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    var httpPromise = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: {
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log("POST SUCCESSFUL");
        return response;
    }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log("POST REJECTED");
        throw response;
    });
```

If the server API can only accept a POST with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then the data needs to be [URLencoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type):

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    var httpPromise = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: {
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        //URLencode the request
        transformRequest: $httpParamSerializer
        //OR
        //transformRequest: $httpParamSerializerJQLike
    });
};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
- [AngularJS $httpParamSerializer Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer)
- [AngularJS $httpParamSerializerJQLike Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy/paste?

```
$username=$ _POST[ 'username']; $password=m d5($_POST[ 'password']);
```

$_POST has a space and md5 too.
Should be:

```
$username=$_POST['username']; $password=md5($_POST['password']);
```

Comment: it's fine in my code I think that happened when I pasted code here it